# How many kinds of divinities of nature are there in Greek mythology?

Tags: greek, gods

How many kinds of divinities of nature are there in Greek mythology?

I heard that Polythemus was a demigod because his father was a god and mother was a nymph.

Merriam-Webster defines nymph as

> The meaning of NYMPH is any of the minor divinities of nature in classical mythology represented as beautiful maidens dwelling in the mountains, forests, trees, and waters.

Is a nymph a divinity of nature but less divine than a god and a demigod, but more than a human being?

I also learned that Scylla was a sea monster. Is a monster also a divinity of nature?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.